# doctrine 2.1 - entity cannot be persisted

Tags: php, memory-management, doctrine-orm

**Doctrine version 2.1**

i am persisting a lot of objects, that is why I have to do `$this->entityManager->clear()` after `$this->entityManager->flush()`, however it causes a well known error:

> Exception: "A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Entities\A#B' that was not configured to cascade persist operations
>   for entity: Entities\B@00000000550760cc00000000b0edf71c. Explicitly
>   persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on
>   the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes the
>   problem implement 'Entities\B#__toString()' to get a clue."

It works for the first flush, but it does not work for all the others. When I comment `$this->entityManager->clear();`

Here is the code sample:

```
  if ($flushCounter % 50 == 0) {
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $this->entityManager->clear();
    //$this->entityManager->detach($B); <- with these two lines commented I tried to fix the error, but it did not work
    //$B = $this->entityManager->find(ENTITY_NAMESPACE . "\B", (int) $B_id);
  }
  $flushCounter++;
```

I will repeat that commenting out clear() function fixes the issue but i do not want to do that unless there is a better way to manage memory

Comment: It seems like you are changing entities that are in associations, but on the inverse side of the association. So when you try to persist the owning side, since there isn't the `CASCADE: persist` set, it throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing is persist on $B after fetching it again.

```
 if ($flushCounter % 50 == 0) {
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $this->entityManager->clear();
    $B = $this->entityManager->find(ENTITY_NAMESPACE . "\B", (int) $B_id);
    $this->entityManager->persist($B);
  }
  $flushCounter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me was to clear only the entity that was getting inserted in huge amounts (> 500.000), leaving the rest of the associated objects of that entity in memory

```
if ($repcount++ % 1000 == 0) {
    $em->flush();   
    $em->clear('Entity\Class\Using\Memory');
}
```

This though afaik only works with never versions of doctrine (> 2.2.0) and symfony2 (>2.1)